# Vue Routing for filters with multiple queries

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I’m writing my first vue-app and while implementing the filters a lot of questions arise.

I have created lists with checkboxes for each property. The checkboxes have a change-event to adjust the url and send a get-request. One key can have several values. How can I implement this with vue?

A first test to adjust the URL looked like this:

```
router.push({ name: 'transactions' , query: { property: item.value} });
```

This works fine with one value, but I want to have multiple values for one key.

Many pages solve this with: xy.com/z?property=x%y

I could not find out if this scheme is only recommended or if it has to be solved that way. How I can implement it with vue I could not find out too.

I would also like to know how I can extend the route. The following statement always overwrites the URL instead of extending it.

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'transactions', query: Object.assign({}, this.$route.query, { property: item.value })});
```

I am grateful for any help

Comment: I can think of a solution:
when there is a checkbox checked instead of making url for only one checkbox value, create url for all checkbox.
If user checked checkbox a, and you have 2 other checkbox b and c, 
generate url for all like 
```
router.push({ name: 'transactions' , query: { property1: a.value, property2: b.value, property3: c.value } });


```

Comment: You can not extend/patch the current route/URL - you can either fully replace it with another route (`another` is important here - otherwise you will get an exception about duplicate navigation) or keep it in the navigation history and push a new route at the top of the history stack. There is no other way.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help, then I'll be able to do that with the URLs for different key/values. Do you also have an idea about one key with multiple values?